# Log into website from website

Tags: credentials

I have a webapp that saves the credentials (user & pass) for a website B. Is it possible to click on a link in A and have that sign me into site B in a new browser window?

For example: say A has my pinterest user & pass. If I click on a link in A that says "sign into pinterest" can that open a new windows and let me start browsing pinterest as if I signed in?

Comment: I think this is pretty much possible. Stackexchange is doing it as well as some other sites. You would pass on user name and password to Site B when a link is click on Site A. Or you can use sessions to pass the data.

Comment: what I was thinking was log into the site on the server, then send the cookies back in the response. Then with those cookies somehow add them to the browser and then you are effectively logged in. But I don't know if there are browser security restrictions on site A setting cookies for site B, etc...

Answer (score 0):

This is possible if the site in question gives you some sort of interface (like OAuth) to do that. You cannot just submit data for the user in the other website's regular login form. (assuming they have some CSRF protection, which they should.)